# Meteor MongoDB database localhost vs server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I made a site with Meteor and it works perfectly on localhost, but not on the server. I have a collection in my mongoDB that I fill using a python-script, this script filled both my local as server mongoDB. I can see that it is filled using a database manager.  However the call in my localhost prints an array with the documents, the same code/action on the website on the server returns an empty array.

I really have no clue what the problem could be, somebody that can help me figure this out?

python-script, same for local as on server!

```
def write_data(documents, collection_name):
    # when running locally
    #client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 3001)
    #db = client.meteor

    # on the server
    client = MongoClient(mongoURL, username=****,
                         password=****)
    db = client.mercurius

    if collection_name in db.collection_names():
        collection = db[collection_name]
        collection.drop()

    new_collection = db[collection_name]
    new_collection.insert_many(documents)

    cursor = new_collection.find({})
    for document in cursor:
        print(document)
```

I use mup to setup the containers, it works for the other things, my code. mongoURL in mup is same as in this script above.

```
Meteor.call( 'getDBinfo', function(err, response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(err);
});
```

The above call in meteor returns a full array(53 documents) on localhost, empty on server. Both have an undefined err.

Comment: Can you please add some code on how you a) connect to your external database and b) how you create your collections

Comment: I edited it a little bit